# Linear transformation of polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, linear-transformations

So I'm working on the homework for my Linear Algebra course, and I'm stuck at the following question.

Consider the map: $$ T: P_3 \to P_3 $$
given by:
$$T(p(x)) = p(3) + 2x * p'(x)$$
where p'(x) denotes the derivative of p(x).

I need to prove that this is a linear transformation.

I proceded to prove that:
$$ T(u+v) = p(3) + 2(u+v)*p'(u+v) = p(3)+2u*p'(u)+p(3) +2v*p'(v) = T(u) + T(v)$$
However, I'm stuck trying demonstrate that this is in fact true.

Can someone please help?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is what you plugin. You want to plugin polynomials as $p,u,v \in P_3$ (addition of two polynomials is still a polynomial) and not $x$. (Hence it would be more clearly to define $T(p) (x)=p(3)+2x \cdot p'(x)$ instead, but I will stick with your notation)

\begin{align*}
T(\lambda u(x)+v(x))&=(\lambda u+v)(3)+2x\cdot (\lambda u+v)'(x)\\
&=(\lambda u)(3)+v(3)+2x \cdot ((\lambda u)'(x)+v'(x))\\&
=\dots
\end{align*}

You also have to show if this is well defined? (meaning is still $T(p(x)) \in P_3$?)

Comment: thanks! after using the proper notation everything became more clear!

Answer (score 0):

Evaluation at 3 is a linear transformation, that is the map $f(x)\mapsto f(3)$.

The map $f(x)\mapsto xp'(x)$ is also a linear transformation, because it is the composition of derivative map and multiplication map ( mult. by $x$).

Being a  sum of  two linear transformations, $T$ of your question  is also one.